# Where can I find the rpg 'HYBRID'?

Tags: hybrid-rpg

Does anyone know where I can find a full copy of HYBRID? I have searched the internet for several hours and found only an incomplete copy of the rules, I know that the full thing isn't really complete however I would like to try playing it.

Comment: Based on what I'm reading, I'm not sure a "full" copy exists? Most websites describe it as an incomplete game. Do you have an idea of what should be in the complete copy?

Comment: Around 550 posts, some vague and illogical game mechanics. The copy I found had 20 posts most of which were duplicates and did not even resemble rules. Thanks if you find anything.

Comment: Version 0.21 is composed of 551 "rules", not posts. Yes, most of the things titled "rules" bear no resemblance to actual rules. Welcome to HYBRID, leave all expectations at the door.

Comment: If anyone knows where to find a copy of v0.21 then that would be greatly appreciated, the site which I read hosted it has stopped working.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The official HYBRID RPG site/rules went offline ten years ago, but the latest version, from 2003, is archived by the Internet Archive: [HYBRID RPG version 0.30](https://web.archive.org/web/20030213163300/http://perso.wanadoo.fr/philippe.tromeur/hybrid.htm).

The document itself states that it is only (and exactly) 30% finished. It makes no sense and is unplayable, but nobody will stop you from trying.

Update: There is [apparently a version 0.4 being released](http://rpggeek.com/thread/567737/new-edition) in installments on the [author's blog](http://hybrid-rpg.blogspot.com/). I haven't been able to load it though, but if its issues resolve you should be able to reach it. Being released episodically it's even less complete, ironically.

It also becomes more and more apparent, judging by the tidbits quoted, that it is the ravings of a racist, Marvel-obsessed madman trying to find personal religion/truth through writing an "RPG," and is about as worth reading (nevermind trying to "play") as the [TIMECUBE](http://www.timecube.com/) is worth reading — that is to say, not at all, except perhaps as a party trick. The only way in which HYBRID is an RPG is in calling itself one, and in every other way it is not an RPG.

Still, no-one will stop you from trying.

Comment: "More and more"? I thought this was already painfully obvious 10 years ago.

Comment: @mcv Take "painfully obvious" and then increase it. ;)

Comment: Thanks for the update, I still prefer v0.3 though.